# Можно ли узнать пересечение N множеств по частям <N?

Tags: множества, алгоритм

Есть списки уникальных целых значений. Каждый список назову «множеством».

Есть возможность узнавать кол-во **уникальных** элементов для максимум M множеств. Например:

```
/* допустим, мн-ва A и B такие, на деле состав множеств неизвестен */
A = [1,2,3]
B = [2,3,4,5]
/* можем задавать такие запросы и получать такие результаты: */
unique(A,B) = 5  /* 1,2,3,4,5 */
unique(A) = 3
unique(B) = 4
```

**Хочется узнать** кол-во **общих** элементов для N множеств, где N > M. Возможно ли это в заданных условиях?

Запросов про `unique()` можно делать много. Как отсюда можно прийти к числу общих, для 2, понятно:

```
unique(A) + unique(B) - unique(A,B) = общее ядро A и B
```

`3 + 4 - 5 = 2` в примере выше.

Не соображу, как поступать с бОльшим числом множеств. К сожалению, прогулял теорию множеств в своё время, поэтому прошу помощь у зала.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что `A, B, C, D` - мультимножества? (В противном случае `unique(A) == length(A)`, что вряд ли можно назвать интересным случаем)?

Comment: @Котик, даже в случае множеств получается нормальная логическая задача, которую раньше решали в уме, а сейчас -- с использованием логического программирования. Только вот условия задачи (система логических уравнений) должны однозначно определять ответ.

Comment: @Котик завидую, потому что мне вопрос (условия задачи) непонятен.

Comment: Всё проще некуда, без терминологии профи теории множеств.

@Котик_хочет_кушать: три первых вопроса «Да». Множествами именую массивы уникальных натуральных чисел. Внутри одного элементы не повторяются.

@alexlz в одном запросе можно "спросить" максимум про M множеств. Требуется получить общее ядро для N множеств, и неравенство «`N > M`» именно про эти N и M. Например, спросить за один раз можно максимум про 3 любых множества. А надо получить общее ядро 15, задав серию «правильных» вопросов.

Comment: Пример

* A=[1,2,3,4,5,10];u(A)=6;
* B=[2,3,4,5,6,11];u(B)=6;
* C=[3,4,5,6,1,12];u(C)=6;
* u(A,B)=4;
* u(B,C)=4;
* u(A,C)=4;
* u(A,B,C)=3

Отсюда вопрос. Как получить нечетное число 3 для A*B*C путем сложения и вычитания четных чисел 4 и 6. Ответ: никак.  
Смысл в том, что конъюнкцией и дизюнкцией не обойтись. Нужны еще операции. Например, отрицание или разность.

Comment: @Yura-ivanov логика понятна, но утвеждение «никак» пока бездоказательно: почему не ввести параметр кол-ва элементов, и какую-нибудь формулу типа `(2uA+2uB+2uC+uAB+uAC+uBC)/(3+1)^2` % )

Comment: @sergiks ну вы же привели метрику. Кроме того, количество элементов не совсем честная дизъюнкция, говорит только о наличии совпадающих элементов, а не о том какие именно, т.е. то, что у вас в примере получилось 3+4-5=2 вам просто повезло ибо двумерный случай рассмотрели, уже для трех множеств вариантов может быть много.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Задача в общем случае нерешаема.

Пример: пусть `M = 1`, `N = 2`, все множества одноэлементные. Вы никак не сможете узнать, эти множества совпадают или нет.

Comment: 1,2 — частный случай. На деле ближе к M=10, N=30. Думаете, тоже нерешаемо??

Comment: Плюсую за кэповское решение. Т.к.  уверен, что автору вероятностное решение не нужно.

Comment: @sergiks: если задача не решается для каких-то значений параметров, значит, в общем виде она неразрешима. Задача _может_ быть решаема для _некоторых_ значений параметров. Для каких именно -- надо исследовать.

Comment: @sergiks: в общем случае вам нужна [формула включений-исключений](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9). По ней видно, что нужны все объединения множеств до самого `N`, что наталкивает на мысль о неразрешимости в общем случае при `N > M`.